# Deadlock in event processing

Tags: go, goroutine

So I have a channel used for event processing, the main server goroutine select on this channel and call event handlers on each of the event received:

```
evtCh := make(chan Event)
// server loop:
for !quit {
    select {
    case e := <- evtCh:
        handleEvent(e)
        break
    case quit := <-quitCh:
        //finish
}

// for send a new event to processing
func addEvent(e Event) {
    evtCh <- e
}
```

`handleEvent` will call registered handlers on the event type. I have `func registerEventHandler(typ EventType, func(Event))` to handle the register. This program will supports user to write extensions, that means they can register their own handlers to handle events.

Now the problem arise when in user's event handler, they might send new event to the server by calling `addEvent`, this will cause the server to hang since the event handler itself is called in the context of the server's main loop(in the for loop).

How can I handle this situation elegantly? Is a queue modeled by slice a good idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> this will cause the server to hang since the event handler itself is called in the context of the server's main loop

The main loop should never block on calling `handleEvent` and the most common way to avoid that is to use a pool of worker goroutines. Here's a quick **untested** example:

```
type Worker struct {
    id int
    ch chan Event
    quit chan bool
}

func (w *Worker) start {
    for {
        select {
            case e := <- w.ch:
                fmt.Printf("Worker %d called\n", w.id)
                //handle event
                break;
            case <- w.quit:
                return
        }
    }
}


ch := make(chan Event, 100)
quit := make(chan bool, 0)

// Start workers
for i:=0; i<10; i++{
    worker := &Worker{i,ch,quit}
    go worker.start()
}

// 
func addEvent (e Event) {
    ch <- e
}
```

and when you are done, just `close(quit)` to kill all workers.

**EDIT**: From the comments below:

> what is the main loop looks like in this case?

Depends. If you have a fixed number of events, you can use a [WaitGroup](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup%20WaitGroup), like this:

```
type Worker struct {
    id int
    ch chan Event
    quit chan bool
    wg *sync.WaitGroup
}

func (w *Worker) start {
    for {
        select {
            case e := <- w.ch:
                //handle event
                wg.Done()

                break;
            case <- w.quit:
                return
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan Event, 100)
    quit := make(chan bool, 0)

    numberOfEvents := 100

    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(numberOfEvents)

    // start workers
    for i:=0; i<10; i++{
        worker := &Worker{i,ch,quit,wg}
        go worker.start()
    }


    wg.Wait() // Blocks until all events are handled
}
```

If the number of events is not known beforehand, you can just block on the quit channel:

```
<- quit
```

and once another goroutine closes the channel, your program will terminate as well.

Comment: Thanks, what is the main loop looks like in this case? you mean send e to the workers in a round robin fashion?

Comment: You don't need to do anything extra for round robin. When you call `addEvent(myEvent)` the first idle worker will grab the event. I've expanded the answer with an example of a main thread.

Comment: I'd like to understand why make `ch` a buffered channel, what's the benefit compared to unbuffered channel?

Comment: @fluter A buffered channel will protect your sending goroutine from accidentally blocking. If, occasionally, all your worker goroutines are busy and you call `addEvent()`, that call will block. A buffered channel will let you push events to it even when all workers are busy.

Comment: According to the spec, it will block too when the channel is full, right? Although the chance is little in reality I guess.

Comment: Yes, if the buffer is full, it will block until a stop becomes available. You should pick a buffer size where the chance of blocking is very little.

Comment: Make the channel bigger in capacity or add more workers, which is better?

Comment: If you are writing to the channel faster than you can read, *any* buffer will eventually fill up and block. You should always have enough workers to keep the channel empty. The buffer is only for the occasional, temporary situation where writes increase significantly.

Answer (score 1):

To make things more async you can either

- add capacity to event channel

  `evtCh := make(chan Event, 10)`
- call handleEvent(e) asynchronously

  `go handleEvent(e)`
- add event asynchronously in handlers

  `go addEvent(e)`

Or if you want events to be handled in deterministic order you can  call `handleEvent(e)` in handlers directly instead of `addEvent(e)`